# Can MPI sendbuf and recvbuf be the same thing?

Tags: c, mpi

I'm adding together a load of array elements from each process:

```
double rho[1024];
//Some operation to calculate rho for each process;
MPI_Allreduce(rho,rho,1024,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Will having rho as both the sendbuf and recvbuf work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you checked `MPI_IN_PLACE`? According to [MPI_AllReduce man page](http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.5/man3/MPI_Allreduce.3.php) and [MPI doc](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-20-html/node145.htm) it can be used to specify the same buffer for sendbuf and recvbuf as long as you are working inside the same group.

The call would look like:

```
MPI_Allreduce(MPI_IN_PLACE,rho,1024,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: +1 - In-place reductions can be a useful, and the above is the correct way to do it.

Comment: this is an elegant way to do this..his answer needs approval asap.

Comment: How about MPI_Reduce?

Comment: read the man page of MPI_Reduce, it's OK to use MPI_IN_PLACE