# Using MPI_AllReduce with MPI_IN_PLACE in Fortran

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am trying to calculate a sum of a column vector using mpi.

I have read the following thread
[Can MPI sendbuf and recvbuf be the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507865/can-mpi-sendbuf-and-recvbuf-be-the-same-thing)
and found the use of MPI_IN_PLACE would be a good choice to minimize the memory usage for very large data.
However, in my trivial test the mpi_allreduce keeps reporting memory segmentation fault:
`Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.`

I could not figure out what went wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
program mpitest 
implicit none
 include  "mpif.h"
 integer :: i, mprank, mpsize, mpierr
 real(KIND=8), dimension(5) :: Qin 
 
 call MPI_INIT(mpierr)
 call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,mpsize,mpierr)
 call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,mprank,mpierr) 
 write(*,*) mprank,'/',mpsize
 do i = 1, 5
    Qin(i) = (mprank+1)*i
    write(*,*) Qin(i), mprank
 enddo
 call MPI_AllReduce(MPI_IN_PLACE,Qin,5,MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD)
 if (mprank == 0) then 
   do i = 1, 5
    write(*,*) Qin(i)
   enddo
 endif
 
 call MPI_FINALIZE(mpierr)

end program mpitest
```

Comment: you should really `use mpi` (or even better `use mpi_f08`) instead of `include 'mpif.h'`. That could have the compiler spot the error for you: `MPI_Allreduce()` is missing the last `mpierr` argument.

Comment: Uh! added ```mpierr``` to the ```MPI_Allreduce( )``` made it work! Though I have still used ``` include 'mpif.h'``` since ```use mpi``` and ```use mpi_f08``` produces error: ```use statement cannot follow implicit none```. Thanks Gilles!

Comment: The line `use mpi` just needs to come before the line `implicit none`. This is true of all such `use` statements in fortran.

Comment: Do we have a duplicate? If not, it might be useful to answer this one and ahave a duplicate target.

Comment: @VladimirF, if I were going to close as duplicate I'd probably select [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24512592/3157076). While it's not the same routine and the same argument, and the error status is "special" in some way, we don't really need to be so exact.

Comment: But there are only so many useful questions with the answer "you haven't followed the API documentation" one can have.

Comment: Note also `MPI_DOUBLE` is not standard for Fortran - that's the C interface. You probably mean `MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION`